# Connecting Jhipster to Spinnaker?

Tags: jhipster, spinnaker

I'm new to spinnaker. Since the Jhipster uses microservice and it has its own load balancer(Netflix OSS).
How could it be connected to Spinnakers load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker does not have load balancer itself. Cloud providers, handled by Spinnaker, does.

May I link the Load balancer definition in Spinnaker docs :

> Load Balancer: A Load Balancer is associated with an ingress protocol and port range, and balances traffic among instances in the corresponding Server Group. Optionally, you can enable health checks for a load balancer, with flexiblity to define health criteria and specify the health check endpoint.

AFAIK JHipster is a framework to develop microservices more than "using" them. But I'm maybe wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming JHipster is configuring the spring-cloud client side load balancing with Eureka, a JHipster app would work well deployed with Spinnaker with the Eureka provider enabled - the Eureka status for the JHipster app would be reflected in the Spinnaker UI as well as being used to gate the progression through a deployment pipeline (Spinnaker would not proceed with the pipeline until the app entered the UP state)